# How to detect Phone Vibration

Tags: windows-phone-7

What is the difference between shake and vibrate?  I need some help on these:

1) How to detect the phone vibration when phone lying on the surface.
2) How to detect the phone vibration when it is hanging.

Your help and code sample much appreciated.  Thanks

--- Update

does shake mean movement along x and y ?

and Virbate means movement Up and down vertically?

```
// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    acc.ReadingChanged += new EventHandler(acc_ReadingChanged);
    acc.Start();
}

void acc_ReadingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerReadingEventArgs e)
    {
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => ThreadSafeAccelerometerChanged(e));
    }

void ThreadSafeAccelerometerChanged(AccelerometerReadingEventArgs e)
{
    XText.Text = e.X.ToString("0.000");
    YText.Text = e.Y.ToString("0.000");
    ZText.Text = e.Z.ToString("0.000");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shake usually involves the use of accelerometer in the phone to detect any shake gesture/event. You may program your application accordingly on the occurrence of shake gesture. Whereas you may use vibration to prompt the user of some kind of output or event that has happened like in a game when you win/lose.

All in all shake is a kind of input gesture and vibration is output gesture.

For accelerometer refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604984.aspx
and for vibration behavior you may start of with this http://blog.xyzzer.me/2012/01/09/vibration-behaviors-for-windows-phone-part-1/

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. Suppose my phone setup with vibrate mode. When someone call my phone, it will vibrate. Can this kind of vibration be detected using accelerometer? a slightest move say x=0.1 cause by vibration for situation like phone lying on desk or holding the phone, can use this accelerometer? Thanks

Comment: In short, can I use accelerometer to detect any movement (x,y,z) that cause by phone's vibration.

Comment: I guess it should work. I tested some code and the accelerometer is sensing the smallest movement in the emulator. But to be of certain you should test it on the device as well. Good luck :)

Comment: Just checking, Is there any other way to detect the phone's vibration?

Comment: I don't know any other method. All the best :)